# Securing Pages From The Public

Tags: php

In my various PHP login systems I have made over the years, I have tried various different ways of securing pages.

I always use a .htaccess, which routes all requests through to the index.php.  However, if you directly type the address for a certain page (if you know it), it will load, which obviously isn't very secure.

On one server I tried putting all my 'secured' pages **outside** of the public_html.  This worked great.  It meant that you could no longer goto 'folder/products/product.php'.  Great! This meant I could put all requests to that page in an include and have complete control over who views that page.

However, I have come accross a problem on a different server, and basically it is not letting me access anything outside of the `httpdocs` folder.  Well, not strictly true, I can access, with FastCGI support turned on, but I get session write errors.  Turn it off, and turn on PHP as Apache Module, and I get `basedir restrictions`.

Okay.  So how can I be sure that a page is **only** accessible by me?  Even if it is in the public folder? Is there some kind of .htaccess I can put in there, that will stop anyone from the outside accessing it? Or would passwords work, if I password EVERY folder, does that mean I can still include the files?

I really need a good final solution on this one.  One that would work on all servers, and the only way I can see that happening is to keep everything inside the public folder.

Comment: Add a `.htaccess` with `deny from all`.

Comment: @Yoshi Add a .htaccess to every folder?

Comment: at least every one on the root level (so to speak). But it will be inherited by subfolders (as long as it issn't overwritten somewhere)

Comment: Thank you.  If you want to put that as an answer I will tick it.  That is what I wanted!

Comment: `However, if you directly type the address for a certain page (if you know it), it will load` Well only if you didn't complete your job in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prohibit access to a directory and all it subdirectories you can add a `.htaccess` with `deny from all`. As long as this is not overwritten by a "deeper" htaccess file, it will be enough.

Also you might want to check how "big" frameworks structure their code. (e.g. symfony, zend, etc).

Further reading:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html
- http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/htaccess-deny-from-all-restrict-directory-access.html

Comment: Thank you very much.  I didn't know about this rule.  This is a big help.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to do something like this, basically forbidding those from being run as top-level scripts:

In all of your endpoints that you expect to serve, as the first thing you do, set a global flag.

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['INSIDE_AN_ENDPOINT'] = true;
```

Then, in each of your include files, just make sure that flag is set before proceeding.

```
<?php
if (!isset($GLOBALS['INSIDE_AN_ENDPOINT'])) { header('Status: 403 Forbidden'); exit; }
```

Comment: I dont like that method.  I don't want to have to put something into every page to make sure it is loading correctly.